# How do I type in image links and make them appear on the yellow view below?

Tags: react-native

```js
class Newsfeed extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
  };
   render(){
    return (
       <View>

      <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>Junior Facebook</Text>
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "column"}} />
      <View style={{top: 20, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 180, backgroundColor: "lightblue"}}>
      <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 150,
            borderStyle: "solid",
            borderWidth: 2,
            fontSize: 30
          }}
          placeholder="New Post"
          onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState({text})}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ backgroundColor: "green", marginLeft: 220, width: 80, height: 30 }}
        >
          <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Enter</Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>

      <View style={{marginTop: 30, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 180, backgroundColor: "pink"}} >
      <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 65, height: 45, marginLeft: 260, marginTop: 160}}><Text>Share</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 65, height: 45, marginLeft: 230, marginTop: -45}}><Text>Like</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={{marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 130, backgroundColor: "yellow"}} >
      <Image source={{uri: this.state.text}} style={{width:200, height: 90}} />
     </View>
    </View>
  ) 
  }
}
```

The above is my code, and currently, when I type in an image link, an image appears on the yellow view below. I want my image to appear when I type in an image link and click the "Enter" button. Also, I want my previous images to stay in the yellow box. How can I do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another state for that and update it on click on the button as below code

```js
class Newsfeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: "",
            imageURL: ""
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>Junior Facebook</Text>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }} />
                <View
                    style={{
                        top: 20,
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        width: 300,
                        height: 180,
                        backgroundColor: "lightblue"
                    }}
                >
                    <TextInput
                        style={{
                            height: 150,
                            borderStyle: "solid",
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            fontSize: 30
                        }}
                        placeholder="New Post"
                        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                        value={this.state.text}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: "green",
                            marginLeft: 220,
                            width: 80,
                            height: 30
                        }}
                        onPress={this.handlePress}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Enter</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 30,
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        width: 300,
                        height: 180,
                        backgroundColor: "pink"
                    }}
                >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{ width: 65, height: 45, marginLeft: 260, marginTop: 160 }}
                    >
                        <Text>Share</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{ width: 65, height: 45, marginLeft: 230, marginTop: -45 }}
                    >
                        <Text>Like</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 10,
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        width: 300,
                        height: 130,
                        backgroundColor: "yellow"
                    }}
                >
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: this.state.imageURL }}
                        style={{ width: 200, height: 90 }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    handlePress = () => {
        this.setState({ imageURL: this.state.text });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an array of links in the state and display it by mapping the array elements to images. 
The code would be like this

```
class Newsfeed extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        text: '',
        images: []
    }
};
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>Junior Facebook</Text>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }} />
            <View style={{ top: 20, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 180, backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}>
                <TextInput
                    style={{
                        height: 150,
                        borderStyle: "solid",
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        fontSize: 30
                    }}
                    placeholder="New Post"
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "green", marginLeft: 220, width: 80, height: 30 }}
                    onPress={() => {


                        this.setState({ images: [...this.state.images, this.state.text] });
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Enter</Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>

            <View style={{ marginTop: 30, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 180, backgroundColor: "pink" }} >
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 65, height: 45, marginLeft: 260, marginTop: 160 }}><Text>Share</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 65, height: 45, marginLeft: 230, marginTop: -45 }}><Text>Like</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 130, backgroundColor: "yellow" }} >
                {this.state.images.map(link => <Image source={{ uri: link }} style={{ width: 200, height: 90 }} />)}
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}